# 'Error: too many re-renders' on simple React-Redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-dom

I'm trying to build a simple app using React-Redux that gets a quote from state and renders it to the page. Right now, I have the app's main functionality in a functional component called `QuoteBox`, which I render in another functional component called `App`, which is then wrapped in the React-Redux `Provider` and finally rendered into the page:

`./src/features/QuoteBox/QuoteBox.jsx`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {
  initialize,
  getNewQuote,
  selectQuote
} from './quoteBoxSlice'
import styles from './QuoteBox.module.css'

export function QuoteBox() {
  const currentQuote = useSelector(selectQuote)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
    <div
      className={styles['quote-box']}
      onLoad={dispatch(initialize())}
      >
      <p className={styles['text']}>{currentQuote['quote']}</p>
      <p className={styles['author']}>{currentQuote['author']}</p>
      <button
        className={styles['new-quote']}
        onClick={dispatch(getNewQuote())}
        >New Quote!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`./src/features/QuoteBox/quoteBoxSlice.js`

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

function randomIndex(n) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
}

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'quotebox',
  initialState: {
    allQuotes: [],
    currentQuote: {}
  },
  reducers: {
    initialize: state => {
      state['allQuotes'] = [
        { author: 'Author One', quote: 'Quote One' },
        { author: 'Author Two', quote: 'Quote Two' },
        { author: 'Author Three', quote: 'Quote Three' },
        { author: 'Author Four', quote: 'Quote Four' },
        { author: 'Author Five', quote: 'Quote Five' }
      ]
      state['currentQuote'] = state['allQuotes'][
        randomIndex(state['allQuotes'].length)
      ]
    },
    getNewQuote: state => {
      state['currentQuote'] = state['allQuotes'][
        randomIndex(state['allQuotes'].length)
      ]
    }
  }
})

export const { initialize, getNewQuote } = slice.actions

export function selectQuote(state) {
  return state['quoteBox']['currentQuote'];
}

export default slice.reducer
```

`./src/app/store.js`

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import quoteBoxReducer from '../features/QuoteBox/quoteBoxSlice'

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    quoteBox: quoteBoxReducer
  }
})
```

`./src/App.jsx`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { QuoteBox } from './features/QuoteBox/QuoteBox'

function App() {  
  return (
    <div>
      <QuoteBox />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

`./src/index.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import store from './app/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

The error page gave me the following feedback:

```
**18 stack frames were expanded.**
**renderWithHooks**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14815
**updateFunctionComponent**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17034
**beginWork**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18610
**callCallback**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188
**invokeGuardedCallbackDev**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237
**invokeGuardedCallback**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292
**beginWork$1**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23203
**performUnitOfWork**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22157
**workLoopSync**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22130
**performSyncWorkOnRoot**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21756
**flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl/<**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11089
**unstable_runWithPriority**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653
**runWithPriority$1**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11039
**flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11084
**flushSyncCallbackQueue**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11072
**unbatchedUpdates**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21909
**legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24757
**render**
C:/Users/jpaul/Desktop/quote-box/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24840
```

What could be causing an infinite loop here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `QuoteBox` you're calling the dispatch when you render, as opposed to when you click. This changes the quote, causing a renreder of the `QuoteBox` and thus another dispatch, ad infinitum. Change this:

`onClick={dispatch(getNewQuote())}`

to this:

`onClick={() => dispatch(getNewQuote())}`